# Change data type in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to bulk copy data from one table to another. I am getting error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

**Source table**

[source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2RG2.png)

**Destination table**

[destination table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1mHg.png)

Code:

```
SqlCommand cmundefined = new SqlCommand("SELECT CAST(month+'/'+day+'/'+year AS datetime) as date_time, CAST(RIGHT('0000000000'+HSCode,10) AS numeric(13,0)) as code, " +
"HSSystemDescription as name,HSUnit as unit,str(cpc) as cpc,port as port,OriginCountryName as country,HSQuantity as netweight, " +
"FOB as fob,InternalFreight as freight,Insurance as insurance,Discount as discount,OtherCharges as other,CIF as cif,Sector as sector,rate FROM rawdata WHERE TradeFlow = 'Imports' AND month=" + i.ToString(), cnn);

cnn.Open();
SqlDataReader rrundefined = cmundefined.ExecuteReader();
Conn.Open();

ses = i;
//OdbcDataReader myReader = catCMD.ExecuteReader();

SqlBulkCopy sbcx = new SqlBulkCopy("server=" + server_name + ";database=TRADE_2018;Integrated Security=SSPI");
sbcx.BulkCopyTimeout = 3600;
sbcx.ColumnMappings.Add("cpc", "cpc");
sbcx.DestinationTableName = "input";

sbcx.WriteToServer(rrundefined);
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error, and how to change data type of the column in the `select` statement?

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QW1r.png)

Comment: Which field is it?

Comment: Show us sample data for the source table.  _Don't_ post image links, but rather actual text.

Comment: @juergend I think `datetime` or `code` field

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added sample data image

Comment: Tim specifically said "Don't post image links, but rather actual text." Then why do you do exactly what he said you shouldn't do?

Answer (score 0):

Run this query on the rawdata table to find any non-numeric values:

```
select
    HSCode
from 
    rawdata
where
    HSCode is not null and
    try_cast(HSCode as numeric(13,0)) is null;
```

Do the same for HSQuantity and any other columns that should be numeric.

This will tell you if you have non-numeric data where you expect numeric.